# GSheets VLookup array to search multiple tabs for multiple references

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

So I have a Google sheet with multiple tabs and need to reference data in column A in order to display the data in rows B, C, D, E etc

Here's what I currently have: `=ArrayFormula(IF(lEN(B4), IFerror(VLOOKUP(T(B4),{Data1!$A$1:$A$561; Data2!$A$1:$A$673; Data3!$A$1:$A$1217, Data4!$A$1:$A$1217},1,1,FALSE),"Not found"),))`

I'm not getting any errors, but I'm also not getting any results, even using exact values so it makes me think I'm missing something.
Any ideas?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(LEN(B4), IFNA(VLOOKUP(B4, 
 {Data1!A1:E561; 
  Data2!A1:E673; 
  Data3!A1:E1217; 
  Data4!A1:E1217}, {2,3,4,5}, 0), "Not found"), ))
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I had forgotten about Indexing, thank you!
Also, here's the test speadsheet I'm working with, since you requested:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C_C3QiYQl81CSBfGwBS5NOykyNhG5UZwRVsh4AuuFnQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Ah ha, it was the T function then. Good to know it really was redundant. Thank you!